# Disable preview when scanning with MacOSX

Tags: macos, scanning, hp-photosmart, preview.app

Is there any way to disable preview when scanning in flatbed mode? I don't understand why does it automatically scan a preview since I usually rescan the whole area: it's just a waste of time!

[image]

I must precise that I'm using HP Photosmart 7510 as you can see on the (french) dialog.